# Dent in the wheel - is this bad?

Tags: wheels

While putting back a tire without appropriate tools (screwdriver...), I made a dent in the wheel (aluminum, I think). Is this bad ? Do I risk more than a puncture driving with this ? It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is bad. You might have some luck hammering that out, but I'd consider the rim to be trashed. I would expect the bent-in part will dig into the sidewall and shred it, and/or prevent the tire's bead from staying locked on, which would lead to tire blow-off.

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like I'll have to change the wheel soon then. It is quite worn anyway. Thanks !

Comment: To be honest, I am using screwdrivers all the time - but I never managed to do this. How on earth?!

Comment: It will mainly cause problems with the brakes. The pads are likely to catch and cause a violent lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to provide an answer based on a picture but I would not commute to work on a wheel like that. If I had a light trail by my house I'd risk a slow ride or two to see how things hold up. But I'd be looking for a replacement wheel (not so easy now that COVID has messed up everyone's supply chains). Also check that the wheel wasn't bent out of true (center).

I'd wager your brakes don't work quite right when they clamp down on that dent. Over time the dent would likely accumulate grime from the road and from your break pads. Then you're in for uneven brake wear on one brake track and pad.  So long term I don't think you can count on using that wheel.

Comment: Thanks -- it seems like a good plan is to use it until I can get a new one.